# sensorManager StepCount event value suddenly soars in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors

I get step count from `sensorManager` in ForegroundService.

```
// 기본
    sensorManager =
        applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
```

And as you may know, TYPE_STEP_COUNTER gets step count of all steps since device is rebooted,  I need to reset 0 when new day comes.

So when this sensorManager firstly registered I store step count as `dummy` in DB.

`UI step count` is shown as `sensorManager step count - dummy`.

And when new day comes, I add that day's step count to dummy.

For example,

1st day- dummy: 200, step: 20
2nd day- dummy: 220, step: 0 -> new count starts.

something like this.

```
 override fun onSensorChanged(sensorEvent: SensorEvent?) {

        stepCount = sensorEvent!!.values[0].toInt()

        Log.d("걸음", "$stepCount")

        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val yesterdayCal = Calendar.getInstance()
        yesterdayCal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
        val yesterday = dateFormat.format(yesterdayCal.time)
        val todayCal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val today = dateFormat.format(todayCal.time)

        if (stepCount == 0) {
            // 리부팅 된 경우

            db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { userSteps ->
                    if (userSteps.contains(today)) {
                        // 리부팅: 오늘 걸음수 있는 경우
                        Log.d("걸음", "리부팅: 오늘 걸음수 있는 경우")
                        val todayIngStep = (userSteps.data?.getValue(today) as Long).toInt()
                        if (todayIngStep != 0) {
                            // 리부팅: 누적 걸음수 0이 아닌 경우 -> *일반적 리부팅
                            Log.d("걸음", "리부팅: 누적 걸음수 0이 아닌 경우 -> *일반적 리부팅")

                            val newTodayIngStepSet = hashMapOf(
                                "dummy" to -todayIngStep
                            )
                            db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                                .set(newTodayIngStepSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            StepCountNotification(this, todayIngStep)

                            val userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                today to todayIngStep
                            )

                            val periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "$userId" to todayIngStep
                            )

                            // user_step_count
                            db.collection("user_step_count")
                                .document("$userId")
                                .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            // period_step_count
                            db.collection("period_step_count")
                                .document(today)
                                .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "todayStepCount" to todayIngStep
                            )
                            userDB.document("$userId")
                                .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                                putExtra(
                                    "todayTotalStepCount",
                                    todayIngStep
                                )
                            }
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                                .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                        } else {
                            // 리부팅: 누적 걸음수 0인 경우
                            Log.d("걸음", "리부팅: 누적 걸음수 0인 경우")

                            val newTodayIngStepSet = hashMapOf(
                                "dummy" to 0
                            )
                            db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                                .set(newTodayIngStepSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            StepCountNotification(this, 0)

                            val userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                today to 0
                            )

                            val periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "$userId" to 0
                            )

                            // user_step_count
                            db.collection("user_step_count")
                                .document("$userId")
                                .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            // period_step_count
                            db.collection("period_step_count")
                                .document(today)
                                .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "todayStepCount" to 0
                            )
                            userDB.document("$userId")
                                .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                                putExtra(
                                    "todayTotalStepCount",
                                    0
                                )
                            }
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                                .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                        }
                    } else {
                        // 리부팅: 오늘 걸음수 없는 경우 -> 새로운 날 (DateChange보다 먼저 작동)
                        Log.d("걸음", "리부팅: 오늘 걸음수 없는 경우 -> 새로운 날 (DateChange보다 먼저 작동)")

                        val newTodayIngStepSet = hashMapOf(
                            "dummy" to 0
                        )
                        db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                            .set(newTodayIngStepSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        StepCountNotification(this, 0)

                        val userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                            today to 0
                        )

                        val periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                            "$userId" to 0
                        )

                        // user_step_count
                        db.collection("user_step_count")
                            .document("$userId")
                            .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        // period_step_count
                        db.collection("period_step_count")
                            .document(today)
                            .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        val todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                            "todayStepCount" to 0
                        )
                        userDB.document("$userId")
                            .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        val intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                            putExtra(
                                "todayTotalStepCount",
                                0
                            )
                        }
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                            .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                    }
                }
        } else {
            // 리부팅 x
            Log.d("걸음", "리부팅 x")

            db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { userStepCount ->
                    if (userStepCount.contains("dummy")) {
                        // 리부팅 x: 더미 값이 있는 경우 -> 처음 시작 x
                        val dummyStepCount = (userStepCount.data?.getValue("dummy") as Long).toInt()

                        if (userStepCount.contains(today)) {
                            // 리부팅 x: 오늘 값이 있는 경우 -> *잘 작동 중
                            Log.d("걸음", "리부팅 x: 오늘 값이 있는 경우 -> *잘 작동 중")

                            todayTotalStepCount = stepCount - dummyStepCount

                            StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)

                            val userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                today to todayTotalStepCount
                            )
                            val periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "$userId" to todayTotalStepCount
                            )

                            // user_step_count
                            db.collection("user_step_count")
                                .document("$userId")
                                .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())
                            // period_step_count
                            db.collection("period_step_count")
                                .document(today)
                                .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())


                            val todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "todayStepCount" to todayTotalStepCount
                            )
                            userDB.document("$userId")
                                .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                                putExtra(
                                    "todayTotalStepCount",
                                    todayTotalStepCount
                                )
                            }
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                                .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                        } else {
                            // 리부팅 x: 오늘 값이 없는 경우 -> 잘 작동 x
                            Log.d("걸음", "리부팅 x: 오늘 값이 없는 경우 -> DateChange보다 먼저 새로운 날")

                            val newDummySet = hashMapOf(
                                "dummy" to stepCount
                            )
                            db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                                .set(newDummySet, SetOptions.merge())

                            StepCountNotification(this, 0)

                            val userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                today to 0
                            )

                            val periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "$userId" to 0
                            )

                            // user_step_count
                            db.collection("user_step_count")
                                .document("$userId")
                                .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            // period_step_count
                            db.collection("period_step_count")
                                .document(today)
                                .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                                "todayStepCount" to 0
                            )
                            userDB.document("$userId")
                                .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                            val intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                                putExtra(
                                    "todayTotalStepCount",
                                    0
                                )
                            }
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                                .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                        }
                    } else {
                        // 리부팅 x: 더미 값이 없는 경우 -> 처음 시작
                        Log.d("걸음", "리부팅 x: 더미 값이 없는 경우 -> 처음 시작")

                        val newDummySet = hashMapOf(
                            "dummy" to stepCount
                        )
                        db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                            .set(newDummySet, SetOptions.merge())

                        StepCountNotification(this, 0)

                        val userStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                            today to 0
                        )

                        val periodStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                            "$userId" to 0
                        )

                        // user_step_count
                        db.collection("user_step_count")
                            .document("$userId")
                            .set(userStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        // period_step_count
                        db.collection("period_step_count")
                            .document(today)
                            .set(periodStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        val todayStepCountSet = hashMapOf(
                            "todayStepCount" to 0
                        )
                        userDB.document("$userId")
                            .set(todayStepCountSet, SetOptions.merge())

                        val intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                            putExtra(
                                "todayTotalStepCount",
                                0
                            )
                        }
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                            .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

and it works perfect..

But in one device, in the middle of one day, step value is soaring even user doesn't walk. (like 0 to 31462)

I check dummy value is well added as new day comes.

then only guess that I can do is sensor manager step count is soaring ..?

I really don't know what happens.

please help me..